# How to make Linux read DOS partition table and create partition devices from loopback?

Tags: linux, partitioning, loopback

```
# blockdev --rereadpt /dev/loop3 
BLKRRPART: Invalid argument
```

How to make a "virtual HDD" in linux. It should be like loopback, but also with with automatic linux's detection of partitions and udev creation of device nodes.

Comment: What O/S are you using? Fedora? Debian? Gentoo?

Comment: For example, Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kpartx` will create device mapper nodes that will allow you to access each partition within a drive image.

```
kpartx -av drive.img
```